# How to identify which view a UIImageView collides with

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, collision-detection, uibezierpath

I have a `UIImageView` travelling on a `UIBezierPath` (call it `enemy`). The bezier path runs across multiple different images. Is there any way for me to get `enemy` to detect a collision between the views the `UIBezierPath` runs across and itself?

But, when it detects the collision between itself and the other views, it has to identify which view it intersected with.

Details if needed:

- None of the images or views are `IBOutlets`. (Not created in the storyboard)
- the `UIBezierPath` has no curves, it's a straight line
- all views the bezier path runs across are adjacent to each other

I would prefer if the answer had max one `CGRectIntersectRect` if-statement, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

send  subviews to  the superview of your images (views) and you get an array of all subviews. send frame to each subview to get the frame rectangels and compare or intersect the  rectangle with the line ore the frame of the travalling imageview.

Comment: First, in this answer having the array is unnecessary. This would just be the same as comparing `enemy` to all the images/views.

Comment: If you don't use a tool that provide that kind of hit detection, you have to compare all. To speed up, You cold implement a Quadtree to hold the image frame rectangle. Than request the quadtree for a spezific range.